# Integrating Norm of vectors

Tags: vector, wolfram-mathematica

I have two vectors which I want to integrate in Matematica. Let the vectors be

```
r = {x, y};
Q = {x1, y1};
```

then I write this command

```
Integrate[
 1/Norm[-((a*Q)/c) + r],
 {a, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> (a*x1)/c > x && x -> 
   Real && (a*x1)/c -> 
    Real && x > 0 && (a*y1)/c -> Real && (a*y1)/c > y && y > 0
 ]
```

Where c is a positive constant. The output yields the same

```
Integrate[1/Norm[-((a Q)/c) + r], {a, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> (a x1)/c > 0 && (a x1)/c > x && x -> 
   Real && (a x1)/c -> Real && x > 0 && (a y1)/c > y && y > 0]
```

Could you please tell me where I am making a mistake?
I would be grateful if you could help me, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
r = {x, y};
Q = {x1, y1};

Integrate[1/Sqrt[(-((a*Q)/c) + r).(-((a*Q)/c) + r)], {a, 0, 1}, 
          Assumptions -> Element[{x, y, x1, y1, a, c}, Reals]]
```

Returns:

```
(*
(1/Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2])c (-Log[c (-x x1 - y y1 +Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2) (x1^2 + y1^2)])]+ 
 Log[x1^2 + y1^2 - c (x x1 + y y1) + 
 (c Sqrt[(x1^2 + y1^2) (x1^2 + c^2 (x^2 + y^2) + y1^2 - 2 c (x x1 + y y1))])/
Abs[c]])

*)
```

Comment: @SEngstrom And also remember to start your comments with "@username" to get that user pinged :)

Comment: Ah thank you - I thought you'd get alerted to any activity on a question you posed...